# Google material-icons uses too much spaces

Tags: css, material-design

I'm making my own website, and struggling with some CSS issues.

[image: 1]]

As you see it, you can see that chrome indicates size of i.material-icons as 30x30.
however, real size of i.material-icons is same as the blue square.

I tried to modify my code several times, asked several people, but couldn't found answers.

I attached my CSS code and locations for #content, .material-icons and .panel, #panel-wrapper below.

Thank you.

P.S. Please don't tell me use jQuery except when there's no way without jQuery. I hope solve this problem with CSS only.

```
#content
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
}

#content > #panel-wrapper
{
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
}

/* this will show article url when readmode=true */
#content > #panel-wrapper > .article-url
{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    left: calc((100% - (100% - 100px)) / 2);
    height: 30px;
    width: calc(100% - 230px);
}

#content > #panel-wrapper > .panel
{
    position: absolute;
    display:inline;
    right: calc((100% - (100% - 100px)) / 2);
    height: 30px;
}

#content > #panel-wrapper > .panel > i
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: can somebody see `.material-icons` css code?

Comment: here : https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/

Comment: First of all, isn't the correct syntax for Google Material Icons to use underscores instead of spaces? As in `<i class="material-icons">lock_outline</i>`.

Comment: Omg, thank you MateBoy! I thought I have to use spaces.

Comment: in the statement `right: calc((100% - (100% - 100px)) / 2);` isn't a `((100% - (100% - 100px)) / 2);` equal to static value 50px?

Comment: well, that makes sense ;)